# Dereferencing a pointer gives an address

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

i have this code snippets

```
    const int col= 5;const int row= 5;

    int a[row][col] = {0};

    int (*p)[col] ;

    p = a;
```

And these statements print the same address

```
    cout <<p;
    cout << endl;
    cout << *p;
```

in my opinion since `p` points to an array of 5 `ints`, dereferencing it
should give the first value which doesn't seem to be the case.
help!

Comment: you need to dereference also the first element of the [col] part. Until now, you are getting only the address of the 1 element of the rows

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin dereferencing still gives the address of the variable **not the actual variable**.

Comment: @blackibiza But i have a  pointer to `a` which is an array and c++ says the name of the array gives the address to the element. isn't it?

Comment: It does indeed give the address of the first element. Each element of a two-dimensional array is a one-dimensional array, so that's what it points to.

Comment: @Mike Seymour got you! but then i am novice to c++ and pointers are giving **a hard time** any suggestion that can help me on how to understand them thouroughly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> since `p` points to an array of 5 `ints`

That much is correct.

> dereferencing it should give the first value

No, it's type is "pointer to array"; dereferencing that gives "array", which decays to an `int*` pointer when you do just about anything with it - including printing it.

If you had a pointer to `int`

```
int * p = a;
```

then `*p` would indeed give the first array element.

Comment: then is the address that i get the same as the address of the first value in that `col` or the array has its own address an entity?

Comment: @samuel: The first element of an array always has the same address as the array itself.